# How to checkout branch on Mercurial SourceTree?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm using SourceTree for Mercurial version control. I know that when using Git I can checkout an old commit, simply to see files as they were in a previous commit. I'm not able to do that or find information about checking out an old commit when using Mercurial or using Mercurial with SourceTree. Is it possible to checkout a commit with mercurial? If it is how do I do it with SourceTree?

Comment: `hg update -r <revision-specifier>`, from the command line. No idea how to do it in any GUI.

Comment: `update` is the command.  No idea about SourceTree but read http://hginit.com for a simple tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Using SourceTree:

On the LHS there is a section devoted to branches.  Click on the branch of interest, and then in the main pane, right-click on the commit of interest. The top-most item in the context menu is "Update to..." (for git, it's "Checkout...").

Comment: What do u mean by LHS? When I right click a commit I do not see a checkout option when using Sourcetree for Mercurial. Only when I use Sourcetree for Git.

Answer (score 0):

as @peak says, your right-click may bring the context menu with the top-most item being "Checkout..." as you can see in the screenshot at http://blog.sourcetreeapp.com/files/2013/10/customactions2.jpg

from the command line you can use `hg update -r <revisionID>` as @torek points out
and also any of its aliases like `hg co <revision>` for instance

command `update` has several aliases: `up`, `checkout`, `co` (see `hg help update` for further details)

Comment: Thanks! I do not see the checkout option when right clicking a commit. Can it be because the repository was build by an old version of Mercurial. Sourcetree was installed recently.

Comment: perhaps you could post a screenshot of your UI with the context menu, otherwise it is hard to take a wild guess

Comment: I doubt it could be due to a version incompatibility issue or anything of the kind, since that is a very basic and vital functionality, it has to be there somehow/somewhere